# SQL join table with the output of a stored procedure

Tags: sql

I want to join the output of a stored procedure with a table. 
I know and i am sure that it is possible because i did it before but, i can't remember how. Could anyone help me with that, please?

Comment: Please retag your question to show your database.

Comment: If you used a UDF instead this would be easy. With SP im not sure if it works.

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-sql-select-from-stored-procedure-using-openquery-openrowset.aspx

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: [How to SELECT * INTO temp table FROM Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 5):

You would have to insert the results of your stored procedure into a temporary table and then join to that.

e.g. `insert into #temp_table exec sp_mySP`

You would have to define the temporary table structure to match the output of your stored procedure though.

Comment: thank you :)
my problem was that i forgot renaming the table returned from the stored procedure when joining between it and the main one